# No mod-mono.so or mod_mono.conf after Install

Tags: server, apache2, mono, webmin

On Ubuntu 12.04, I have webmin and apache2.  With webmin, I did apt-get install mono-complete and everything appeared to install fine.  I put the line "MonoAutoApplication enabled" in httpd.conf and restarted apache2, but it failes with "Invalid command 'MonoAutoApplication', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

All the posts I've read speak of mod-mono.so and mod_mono.conf, but I don't seem to have them.

I tried to find the module or config file

```
    # find / -name "*.so" | grep -i mono
    /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-iomap.so
    /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-aot.so
    /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-cov.so
    /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-log.so
    /usr/lib/libmono-2.0.so
    /usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so
    /usr/lib/libMonoSupportW.so

    # find / -name "*.conf" | grep -i mono
    /etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf
    /etc/fonts/conf.d/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but no clue what it is.
Any help greatly appreciated.